# What would be the best way to improve calcul performance in a big data.table?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

In a single `data.table`, I have many calculs to perform. Simple, but combining many configurations : creating X variables from Y others, making groups based on X different variables, etc...

Step by step, I manage to perform all the calculations I need (with my knowledge in data.table), but my real challenge is called PERFORMANCE. My `data.table` contains millions of lines, and the calculations are made on dozens and dozens of columns.

What I would like to know :

- Is there a better way to write this code to improve performance ?
- Some of my options do not work (1.3 and 2.2, tag with KO) : good approach ? How to write it ?
- My `microbenchmark` seems to show me that the best option depends on the number of lines ? Right ?

Here is my code with a reprex :

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(microbenchmark)

n.row <- 1e5

foo <- data.table(id = 101:(101+n.row-1), 
                  crit = rep(c('fr', 'ca', 'al', 'se', 'is'), 5),
                  val_1 = round(runif(n.row, 0.5, 50), digits = 2),
                  val_2 = round(runif(n.row, 1, 20), digits = 0),
                  val_3 = round(runif(n.row, 1, 5), digits = 0),
                  eff = 28500,
                  num = sample(0:1,n.row, replace = TRUE),
                  num_2 = round(runif(n.row, 1, 10), digits = 1),
                  num_17 = round(runif(n.row, 1, 10), digits = 1),
                  num_69 = round(runif(n.row, 0, 1), digits = 2),
                  num_5 = round(runif(n.row, 10, 20), digits = 0),
                  cof = round(runif(n.row, 0.1, 2), digits = 5),
                  ToDo = rep(1, n.row),
                  grp_1 = sample(LETTERS[c(1,3)], n.row, replace = TRUE))


foo[, c("grp_2", "grp_3") := {
  grp_2 = fcase(grp_1 %in% LETTERS[c(1)], sample(LETTERS[c(5,8,9)], n.row, replace = TRUE),
                grp_1 %in% LETTERS[c(3)], sample(LETTERS[c(14,16)], n.row, replace = TRUE))
  
  grp_3 = fcase(grp_1 %in% LETTERS[c(1)], sample(LETTERS[c(20:23)], n.row, replace = TRUE),
                grp_1 %in% LETTERS[c(3)], sample(LETTERS[c(24:26)], n.row, replace = TRUE))
  
  list(grp_2, grp_3)
}]

# Calcul sd and qa
foo[, sd := (val_1 * cof)]
foo[num == 1, qa := (val_2 * cof)]
foo[num != 1, qa := (val_3 * cof)]

foo1 <- copy(foo)
foo2 <- copy(foo)
foo3 <- copy(foo)

# calcul of qa_X 
var.calc <- names(foo)[str_which(names(foo), "^num.\\d+$")]

# 1.1
for (j in var.calc){
  foo1[, paste0("qa_", str_extract(j, "\\d+$")) := qa * get(j)]
}

# 1.2
setDT(foo2)[, paste0("qa_", str_extract(var.calc, "\\d+$")) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x * qa), .SDcols = var.calc ]

# 1.3 KO
for (j in var.calc){ set(foo3, paste0("qa_", str_extract(j, "\\d+$")) := qa * get(j)) }

# comparaison
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  Test.for = for (j in var.calc){ foo1[, paste0("qa_", str_extract(j, "\\d+$")) := qa * get(j)] },
  Test.set = setDT(foo2)[, paste0("qa_", str_extract(var.calc, "\\d+$")) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x * qa), .SDcols = var.calc ],
  times = 10
)

mbm

# calcul by groups
var.grp <- names(foo)[grepl("^grp.\\d+$", names(foo))]

# 2.1
for (j in var.grp) {
  foo1[, paste0("s.sd.", j) := sum(sd, na.rm = TRUE), by = get(j)]
  foo1[, paste0("s.qa.", j) := sum(qa, na.rm = TRUE), by = get(j)]
}

# 2.2 KO 
setDT(foo2)[, paste0("s.sd.", var.grp) := lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x)), .SDcols = var.calc, by = .SD ]
```

Many thanks for helping or suggestions.

(If I have to split my request, I will).

Comment: I don't think you should be using `:=` inside of `set(...)`.

Comment: This question may be a good fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

1. question: I would use:

   ```
   for (j in var.calc) set(foo3, j = paste0("qa_", str_extract(j, "\\d+$")), value = foo3$qa * foo3[[j]])
   ```

(fixed 1.3 example)

2. question: 2.1 seams fine

Notes:

- you don't need to constantly use `setDT(foo2)`
- read documentation of `data.table`! there are lots of useful example, etc.: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/
- don't look at `microbenchmark`'s, try the code on your real data and time that, because the results(time) will be different and the overhead, that some of `data.table`s functions have, will be insignificant.